# Exit code: ENOENT. spawn prlctl ENOENT failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Exit code: ENOENT. spawn prlctl ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, circleci, electron-builder

While implementing ci/cd pipeline for my electron application through circleci I am facing this error

```
Exit code: ENOENT. spawn prlctl ENOENT  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Exit code: ENOENT. spawn prlctl ENOENT
    at /root/project/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:133:18
    at exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:442:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
From previous event:
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)
From previous event:
    at WinPackager.signApp (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:384:27)
    at WinPackager.doSignAfterPack (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:332:32)
    at WinPackager.doPack (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:317:7)
    at WinPackager.pack (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:136:5)
    at Packager.doBuild (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:442:9)
    at executeFinally (/root/project/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
    at Packager._build (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:376:31)
    at Packager.build (/root/project/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:337:12)
    at executeFinally (/root/project/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
```

Exited with code exit status 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqvt8.png)

Can anyone help me why I am getting that error, I am getting that error only when I am trying to build files for Windows, however my mac build is getting deployed fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to solve the error after switching to circleci windows orbs rather than the docker image provided by electron-builder(electronuserland/builder:wine)